# Dual of representation is irreducible implies the representation is irreducible?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, modules, locally-convex-spaces

Suppose $V$ is an infinite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_p$-representation of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. If its dual representation $V^{\prime}$ is irreducible then, is it always true that $V$ is irreducible?

**Added after the comments of Qiaochu Yuan**

*$V$ is a locally convex $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector space. So the topology on $V$ is locally convex topology and I am taking here the strong dual of $V$. 
One can also work with the special case when the topology of $V$ is defined by a norm.*

Comment: Prove the contrapositive: if $V$ is reducible, it has some invariant subspace $W$. So $V^{\ast}$ admits an invariant map to $W^{\ast}$, whose kernel consists of all linear functionals on $V$ vanishing on $W$ (and is invariant). Whether this is enough to finish depends on what kind of topologies you're considering on $V$, if any.

Comment: I have added the topology of $V$ in the question. Also, following your idea, using Hahn-Banach Theorem, the map $\phi$ from $V^{\prime}$ to $W^{\prime}$ is surjective. This gives $W^{\prime}$ is either $0$ or the full space $V^{\prime}$. How to conclude after that? Does it imply $W=0$ or $W=V$?

Comment: Let $\ker(\phi)$ is $V^{\prime}$. Then I am able to show that $W=0$, because, if not, then for a nonzero vector $w \in W \subset V$, there exists a continuous linear form $\ell$ on $V$ such that $\ell(w)=1$.  I am stuck with the case $\ker(\phi)=\{0\}$. This means that I have to show the following. If $W$ is a closed proper subspace of $V$, and $v \in V, v \notin W$, then there exists a non-zero continuous linear form on $V$ which is zero on $W$. I know that this is true when the base field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Is this theorem true for locally convex $\mathbb{Q}_p$- spaces.Any Ref?